# Value of two variable when only one equation is given.

Tags: linear-algebra

Question- $5^{72}+5^{73}+5^{74}+5^{75} = x \times 5^y$

Also given- both x and y are natural numbers.

> Options are 72, 84. 80 and 74

I had figured out-
$$5^{72}(5^0+5^1+5^2+5^3) = x \times 5^y$$
$$\Rightarrow156 = \frac {x\times5^y}{5^{72}}$$

I don't know what to do next. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Identification beteween both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means $$156\cdot 5^{ 72 }=x\times 5^{ y }\\ x=156,y=72$$

Comment: And here I was thinking I couldn't be any more stupid than I already am.

Comment: no,don't think like that,you have almost done it

Comment: Thanks! BTW does this question have any q/a value? Or should it be closed and/or deleted?

Comment: I see at least $71$ other possible chioices for $x$ and $y$...

Comment: @b00nheT,you are right .I think it is clear from this answer

Comment: To expand my comment: just reduce $y=72$ to $72-k$ and multiply $x$ by $5^k$. The solution is unique if you ask for coprimality. Of course @haqnatural. But I saw that the OP accepted the answer, and thought that the might have possibility missed those.